# What is the shortest way to use a data-attribute as a selector?

Tags: jquery

I must write a script which uses a lot of data-attributes.

```
<span data-myval="123">something</span>
```

Normally I use the data-attribute in this way as a selector.

```
$('[data-myval="123"]').dosomething
```

with a another variable which contains the data-myval-id I do it in this way

```
$('[data-myval="'+$(this).attr('data-myval')+']').dosomething
```

Now I look around but find no final answer if there is a way, to use the data-attribute in a shorter way as a selector?

Comment: Shorter than one line?

Comment: maybe there is a shorthand to write this, what i dont know

Comment: You could put your attributes in a variable. Something like var foo = $('[data-value="foo"]') @mikeD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[data-value] {
  /* Attribute exists */
}

[data-value="foo"] {
  /* Attribute has this exact value */
}

[data-value*="foo"] {
  /* Attribute value contains this value somewhere in it */
}

[data-value~="foo"] {
  /* Attribute has this value in a space-separated list somewhere */
}

[data-value^="foo"] {
  /* Attribute value starts with this */
}

[data-value|="foo"] {
  /* Attribute value starts with this in a dash-separated list */
}

[data-value$="foo"] {
  /* Attribute value ends with this */
}
```

Source: [cc-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/)

You could also put your attributes in variables

```
var foo = $('[data-value="foo"]'),
    thisVal = $(this).attr('data-value'),
    newFoo = $('[data-value="'+thisVal+'"]');
    someElement.attr("data-value", thisVal);
```

Comment: thanks for list all possibilities, as i see there is no shorter way